# if loop does not work logically! in netlogo

Tags: if-statement, netlogo

I have two agents, customers and manufacturers. Each of these turtles have a number of variables which some of them are defined global to be able to be assigned to agents of another type.  I have defined this : If at the end of the year, the purchases of product 1 is higher than both products 2 and 3, that product is distributed in 3 more stores. The problem is that the loop does not work logically. What are defined in the commands are happening while reporter is not true!!

```
ask manufacturers [ 
 if (product1purchases > product2purchases) and (product1purchases > product3purchases) [



set storesavailability storesavailability + 3
  set Brandd 1
  set color red
 ]
```

Why when the condition defined in for if is not true, the commands are executed?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They aren't.  You can prove that to yourself by adding print statements, like this:

```
ask manufacturers [ 
  let _cond ((product1purchases > product2purchases) and (product1purchases > product3purchases))
  print (word "_cond is " _cond)
  if (_cond) [
    print (word "within branch, _cond is " _cond)
    set storesavailability storesavailability + 3
    set Brandd 1
    set color red
  ]
]
```

Comment: Thanks for this great way to check the conditions, but the very weird thing is that when I run the program once, then click on red agents, I see that for some of them product1purchases is fewer than product2purchases! or product1purchases  was fewer than product2purchases. The print says that for example for some of the agents (the blue ones) the condition was true, but for those ones, when I click to inspect, I noticed this inconsistency!

Comment: @Naha The condition will apply to each manufacturer at the time it runs the code in brackets.  You can add more print statements to learn why your expectations are incorrect.  Be confident that the NetLogo is doing precisely what you are telling it to, and try to learn where you are telling it to do something different than you intended.

Comment: Thank you so much Alan. By doing what you said, I could make sure that if is working well. I just could not read the values properly because the window for inspecting the agents was made too small. I tried it several times by the print code you suggested and finally noticed that i had made a mistake! Many thanks :)